# Identify this connector and 2.5 mm pin type

Tags: connector, pins

Can you identify the connector type, and more important the pins?

I was able to find NPP 2.5 mm pins that look the same, but apparently they are smaller than what I need... I'm attaching some photos for reference, the one on the left is the one I need (bigger one).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My [Identiconn utility](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=single_wall_conn_4_latch&s=VH%20(1w)) identifies it as a JST VH connector.

- Female plug housing: [JST VHR-8N](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/VHR-8N/608610)
- Female crimp socket contact: [SVH-21T-P1.1, SVH-41T-P1.1, or SVH-21GH-P1.1](https://www.digikey.com/short/308dqrjz), depending on wire gauge and plating

[image: JST VH plug and contact]

{Source: [Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/VHR-8N/608610)]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much!!! I have been searching them for days, could not find any information about it. I also found the contacts - https://il.farnell.com/jst-japan-solderless-terminals/vhr-8n/connector-housing-rcpt-8pos-1row/dp/2399221
You are a life saver dude!!!